# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'buffer' of undefined

Tags: node.js, react-native

I am struggling to upload an image to mongodb from react native. I am getting the above error.I am able to upload the images via postman. Below is the the NodeJS route handling photo uploads

```
router.post(
  "/users/profile/photo",
  auth,
  upload.single("profilePhoto"),
  async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req);
    const buffer = await sharp(req.file.buffer)
      .resize({ width: 250, height: 250 })
      .png()
      .toBuffer();

    req.user.profile_photo = buffer;
    await req.user.save();
    res.send();
  },
  (error, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(400).send({ error: error.message });
  }
);
```

This the code from react native

```
const profilePhoto = userData.images[0].replace("file:/", "");

    if (profilePhoto.length !== 0) {
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append("profilePhoto", profilePhoto);
      const res = await userApi.uploadProfilePhoto(data);
      if (!res.ok) {
        console.log(res);
        alert(res.data.error);
        return;
      }
    }
```

**Upload function**

```
const uploadProfilePhoto = (photo) =>
  client.post(`${usersEndpoint}/profile/photo`, photo, {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; ",
  });
```

Could anyone help me troubleshoot what i am doing wrong here

**EDIT**
I am adding part of request from past that does not exit on request from react native

```
file: {
    fieldname: 'profilePhoto',
    originalname: 'profile-pic.jpg',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    buffer: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 48 00 48 00 00 ff e1 00 8c 45 78 69 66 00 00 4d 4d 00 2a 00 00 00 08 00 05 01 12 00 03 00 00 00 01 00 01 ... 223959 more bytes>,
    size: 224009
  },
```

**The code from Postman**

```
var axios = require('axios');
var FormData = require('form-data');
var fs = require('fs');
var data = new FormData();
data.append('profilePhoto', fs.createReadStream('/C:/Users/user/Downloads/node-course-images/node-course-images/profile-pic.jpg'));

var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: '127.0.0.1:3000/users/profile/photo',
  headers: { 
    'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2MDA1YmQ0NzkyYTQ1ZDU0ZjA1Y2MwYjUiLCJzdXBlcnVzZXIiOnRydWUsInJvbGUiOiJhZG1pbiIsIm5hbWUiOiJQYXVsIE11dGVzaGkiLCJlbWFpbCI6InN1cGVyQGdtYTlsLmNvbSIsInBob25lIjoiMDcyMjMwNDIyMyIsImlhdCI6MTYxMTk0Mzc2N30.c633qRqz-kQ00duMMJTZzW14hWsLf2Tt6nya_tWfWEY', 
    ...data.getHeaders()
  },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Is that a valid "Content-Type"? Specifically with the `";  "` part

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: I am using node.js + react native

Comment: node.js is a runtime environment not a framework. The first snippet looks like it is express but the pattern is rather common and can be attributed to other frameworks as well.  The error you have is because the `req` object in your `async (req, res)` callback does not have a property `file`. Signature of these functions and object types are defined and provided by the framework, hence the question. To make it simpler,  please update the first snippet with imports you have at the beginning of the file (I hope you don't have imports anywhere but at the very top of the file, yes?)

Comment: What i am doing is am sending photo from react native to mongodb. As i have indicated i am able to send files to the same endpoint from postman. But i am not able to do so from ```react native```. The documentation of sending photos to an api requires that i convert to ```formdata``` which as you can see i have done..yet it it is not working..

Comment: fair enough, I've updated tags accordingly. It won't harm to provide details of the successful call from Postman.

Comment: @Muteshi, can you compare the postman http call with the react native http call? You can use "react native debugger" to see the http request/response in react native.

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Try change the upload function to this:

```
const uploadProfilePhoto = (photo) =>
  client.post(`${usersEndpoint}/profile/photo`, {
    headers: {
     'Accept': 'application/json',
     'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
    body: photo,
  }
});
```

Post the response from this and the older function please.

Answer (score 0):

if your server works with postman request you can try like this, and copy the every request what you want
[image]

Comment: I have updated the question with postman code for node.js But how do i create the equivalent for react native

Comment: I always use axios to send request, but change /C:/Users... to C:/Users/..., delete `/` at first path